# Disabled spinner under Bootstrap-modal's fade

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-modal

Problem example!!!
[image: Problem example!]

I have a spinner(I think that is from `Jquery-UI`, not sure) under the modal'fade, I don't know how to remove it, maybe its a conflict between the libraries, but I need the `Jquery-UI` libraries for other sites of the project.
I can't either select(with the element inspect of chrome) to know what library is using in order to update it.

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalError" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="false" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Advertencia!</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"><p id="popup-MsjError2">Acá se reemplaza</p></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnRegistrarMail">Registrar Mail</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so... **Anyone knows the way to remove it?**

Comment: This does not look like Jquery UI. Their `spinner()` is seen here: http://jqueryui.com/spinner/ it is a  Field element. from the image, it also does not look like the loading graphic that jQuery UI uses. Any errors or alerts in Console?

Comment: Nope, no errors in Console :S

Comment: Well, in that case, you should inspect it, it will either have a class or be part of a class, and you can `hide()` it someway.

Comment: Do you or could you set this up in jsfiddle as an example?

Comment: Nope, imposible, there are so much references, I post this here, because maybe someone knows the loading icon's class. Thanks anyway!